# Convert an NSDate to a Unix timestamp using a particular time zone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, time, timezone, nsdate

I am trying to get the Unix timestamp using a particular time zone (not necessarily the same time zone as the system)

I tried this :

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *curdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];

int unix_timestamp =  [curdate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

This should apparently, give the Unix timestamp (up to seconds) in Australia. However, when I log `curdate`, its still the time in GMT, `timeStamp` being the time in Australia/Melbourne.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `timeIntervalSince1970` returns the number of seconds since midnight on January 1, 1970 **in GMT time**.

If you want the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 at midnight **Melbourne** time, you just need to determine what offset from GMT Melbourne was at, on Jan 1, 1970.

For that, you can use [your NSTimeZone instance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
   NSDate* referenceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 0];
   NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"];
   int offset = [timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate: referenceDate];
   int melbourneTimestamp = unix_timestamp - offset;
```

Or, maybe the last line should be **plus** offset.  Just test the code and see.  I'm not on my Mac right now.

---

**Edit:** see Ayush's comment below.  It looks like the offset is intended to be **added**, not subtracted.

**Edit #2:** after chatting with the poster, the timestamp since 1970 *in Melbourne time* was probably not actually needed.  Most applications will probably never need to keep track of such a time stamp, in any other time zone than GMT.  Convert to time zones when it's time to display times to the user.

Comment: Thanks, its *plus* offset. However, I still fail to understand why this still gave me time in GMT : NSDate *curdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];

Comment: Ok, to explain this, first of all ... you understand that you have a couple lines of code that really do nothing, right?  I'm not sure if you maybe put them there in order to enable some logging?  But, the two lines where you assign `timeStamp` and `curdate` are converting date to string, back to date.  You could easily have just said `curdate = [NSDate date];`.  So, that's the first thing to understand.

Comment: Next, you need to understand that an `NSDate` is just a date. It's not necessarily associated with any time zone, until you convert it to a string, or an integer.  If you use `timeIntervalSince1970`, as I said, that integer value is always expressed in GMT, per the Apple docs.  If you instead convert `curdate` to a string, you could then choose to print it out, displaying the time zone in Melbourne time. But, in the code you post, you don't do that.  I only see you convert `curDate` to an `int`, not to a `NSString`.  So, you don't really use the time zone you plugged into your date formatter.

Comment: @Ayush, If you want to show `curdate` as a string, in the Melbourne time zone, just add one more line: `[dateFormatter stringFromDate: curdate];`.  When I run this (now back at my Mac), I get **2012-06-06 17:46:42**, which I think is correct for Melbourne time right now.

Comment: When you say NSDate is just a date.. and is not necessarily associated with any time zone, how is the "HH:mm:ss" determined by the dateformatter then? There must *some* timezone the date along with h:m:s is corresponding to?

Comment: @Ayush, A `NSDateFormatter` **is** associated with a time zone.  But, **not** a `NSDate`.  You use your date formatter to read in a string like "2012-06-06 17:46:42", and produce a `NSDate`.  Because you've already set the time zone on your formatter, it knows that 17:46:42 must be Melbourne time.  But, after converting string to date, the `curdate` object no longer is associated with Melbourne.  `curdate` is just "now".  "now" is the same for someone in Melbourne as it is for me (in the USA).  So, after you've converted the string back to `curdate`, it's no longer in Melbourne time, *per se*.

Comment: Okay "now" should technically be GMT then? 
This clears up things .. `NSLog(@"%@ ... %@ ... %@", curdate, timeStamp, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:curdate]);`
output is GMT TIME, melbourne time, melbourne time
So, any date is basically GMT unless associated with a string, or an integer (as you've already mentioned) .. Have I got it right now?

Comment: @Ayush, I guess you can think of it that way.  Now is just now.  If you must express it as a clock time, the universal standard would be GMT. So, if you're in the debugger, and **hover** over `curdate`, it will show something like **2012-06-06 08:05:43 +0000**.  Which is the same as 18:05 Melbourne time, if you were to stringily it again with a date formatter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12186/discussion-between-ayush-chaudhary-and-nate)

Answer (score 2):

```
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```