# What is the correct way of showing a timestamp in device timezone?

Tags: ios, timezone, timestamp, nsdate, utc

I've this timestamp : `1439353372`

> This was generated when one of our user (from Canada) sent me a message (in India).

Inside our app – He is seeing following time for that message : `2015-08-11 / 22:22pm` and I'm seeing this `2015-08-12 / 09:52am`. He's seeing this in his iPhone6 and I'm on iPhone6+ simulator.

I think this time is wrong – I'm having so much confusion regarding this timestamp/timezone and dates conversion.

Below is our code to convert timestamp to date and showing it in above format.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1439353372];
NSString *strDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
NSString *strTime = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", strDate, strTime]);
```

I'm not sure this is the correct way of showing date for particular timestamp in user's region?

What should I add in above code such that it'll always show us proper time as per our device time zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found that, the above date and time is correct. In GMT, if you convert above timestamp to `NSDate` you'll get following result: `2015-08-12 / 04:22pm`. So for Canada timezone is `GMT-6` (6 hours back from `2015-08-12 / 04:22pm` time) and India is `GMT+5.30` (5.30 hours ahead from `2015-08-12 / 04:22pm` time). So the result in the question I asked is seems to be pure :)

Comment: Dear downvoter, please let me know a reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the timestamp, add the local time zone:-

```
NSTimeZone *localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[df setTimezone: localTimeZone];
```

While retrieving the timestamp, do the same approach so that you get the proper date and time according to your time zone.

**EDITED:-**

This is how you add time zone to your datestamp, just found it from this [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909805/2714702) as I don't have the time right now to write the code

```
   NSDate* referenceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 0];
   NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
   int offset = [timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate: referenceDate];
   int current = unix_timestamp - offset;
```

Comment: NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970 - this method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference date between current date, GMT and the first instant of 1 January 1970, GMT, so you haven't set any timezone at the time of creation

Comment: @hagile You can check my edited post.Hopefully it helps you.